# SpriteRenderer's flipX is not working as excepted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

sprite.flipX is not working as expected, the log shows it updates the flipx value but it has no effect on the unity SpriteRenderer on my player inspector.
player moving, jumping, and jumping to the sides and all animations work correctly except the change direction of the right walking animation.

This is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D coll; //top platform collision -> line 26
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator anim;
 
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround; // for our new box colider, terrain layer pass
 
    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;
 
    private enum MovementState { idle, walk, jumping, falling, side_jump_left, side_jump_right }
 
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource jumpSoundEffect;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
 
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            //jumpSoundEffect.Play();
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
 
        UpdateAnimationState();
    }
 
    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.walk;
            sprite.flipX = false ;
        }

        else if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            state = MovementState.walk;
            sprite.flipX = true ;
        }
        
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }
 
        if (rb.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }
        if (dirX>0f && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            //jumpSoundEffect.Play();
            state = MovementState.side_jump_right;
           
        }
        else if (dirX<0f && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            //jumpSoundEffect.Play();
            state = MovementState.side_jump_left;
        }
           
 
        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
    }
 
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround); // new box colider for our player (position,size,rotation,vector, offset from our original box)
    }
}
```

If I uncheck the Write defaults mark in the walk animation inspector the problem flips after the right side jump animation is played, the character walk animation is to the right only.

in both cases, the body of the player is moving on the x-axis so input is delivered correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are saying that the behavior is not as expected, but I cannot find any info about what behavior do you expect to see.